# splice method type mismatch

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex

So I have a vector of booleans hidden behind a Arc of a Mutex:

```
let mut vec: Arc<Mutex<Vec<bool>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![false; size]));
```

I then spawn off multiple threads that do work on segments of another vector (of the same size). For example, suppose `size=20`. Then, thread 1 works on indices `0 - 4`, thread 2 works on indices `5 - 9`, and so on.

After each thread has done its work on the segment, I would like to put it back into this `vec` Arc/Mutex/Vector. I'm having a bit of trouble doing that. This is what I have tried so far:

```
let mut vec = next.lock().unwrap(); // Blocks until we can acquire
let mut data = *(& *vec); // Pulls the vector out (type std::vec::Vec<bool>)
data.splice(min..=max, segment.iter().clone()).collect(); // Tries to add our segment in
```

`segment` (seen in the last line) is a `std::vec::Vec<bool>` that was created in the thread.

Hopefully my intentions are clear.

However, I'm getting this error:

```
type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, bool> as IntoIterator>::Item == bool`

data.splice(min..=max, segment.iter().clone()).collect();
     ^^^^^^ expected reference, found `bool`

note: expected reference `&bool`
found type `bool`
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accidentally cloning the iterator with [`.clone()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#tymethod.clone). You probably meant to call [`.cloned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) so the iterator clones its items.

```rust
data.splice(min..=max, segment.iter().cloned()).collect();
```